# capture env vars at binary target's compile time

Tags: rust, environment-variables, macros

I'm a library crator, trying to capture the binary target name of application depending on my lib. "CARGO_PKG_NAME" environment variables set when binary target compiles is exactly what I want. I've tried three method to get it as follow:

```rust
/// this captures the runtime environment variable, and it doesn't 
/// contain "CARGO_PKG_NAME" when being run using elf directly 
std::env::vars()

/// this captures the environment variable when my library compiles, 
/// not the binary target, I just got my library name
env!()

/// and I've tried to write a procedure macro, it also expand 
/// when my library compiles, not binary target, also got my library name
#[proc_macro]
pub fn env_vars(_: TokenStream) -> TokenStream {
    let vars: TokenStream2 =
        std::env::vars().fold(TokenStream2::new(), |acc, a| {
            let first = a.0;
            let last = a.1;
            quote!(
                #acc
                (#first, #last),
            )
        })
    ;

    quote!(
         std::collections::HashMap::from([#vars])
    )
    .into()
}
```

so none of the above solves my problem.
I'd like to know if it's possible to be implemented?

Comment: You can look how [clap](https://docs.rs/clap/latest/clap/index.html) does it in it's `#[derive(Parser)]` implementation.